# Why do my text files return as empty when I import it in python even though there are values in the file?

Tags: python, numpy, text

I have tried to load a text file with 300000 integers in it. I load the text with the following code:

```
import numpy as np 
x = np.loadtxt("signal.txt", delimiter=",")
print(x)
```

And when I try to print the values, they return empty. How do I fix this problem? I've checked that the data set has values in it, and they are there.

Comment: Did you check that the integers are in fact delimited by a `,`?

Comment: Can you post a *small* sample of what the contents of the text file look like?

Comment: Note that it shouldn't return an empty sequence, it should raise an error.

Comment: The dataset consist of two labels (0 and 1). It looks like: 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0..........

Comment: The array prints empty brackets []

Comment: Does the file start with the character: #

Answer (score 0):

This test case should run smoothly on your system. If that is true, you should have some problem with your original signals.txt file.... characters ... encoding ...

```
import numpy as np
import random

# generate file with 0s and 1s
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    text = ', '.join([str(random.randint(0,1)) for _ in range(1000)])
    f.write(text)

array = np.loadtxt('test.txt', delimiter=',')
print(array.shape)
array

# to check signals.txt  ... print content
with open('signals.txt') as f:
    text = f.read()
    print(text)
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what the code is doing. What is the "random.randint" for?

Comment: it returns 0 or 1 randomly. It's just to generate a control file. After that line runs,  'text' will hold a string like the one you described.

Comment: Do you know how I can print just the data from signal.txt? I don't necessarily want the randomly generate values and just the data I imported.

Comment: I'm not sure why but the code prints out 1000 "89998"

Comment: Hard to know. Try to post a sample of the file. Open the file on a low-level editor that shows all characters.